# Grass : how to create attribute row for a new feature?

Tags: python, grass-gis

In a python script, I've created a vector and associated attribute table :

```
grass.run_command('v.edit', map='graph', type='line', tool='create')             
grass.run_command('v.db.addtable', map='graph', columns='cat iNTEGER, adj INTEGER')
grass.run_command('v.db.connect', flags='p', map='graph')
```

then I create features in this map with :

```
grass.read_command('v.edit', flags='n', tool='add', map='graph',type='line', input=fichtemp)
```

But I can't find a way to create a row in the attribute table for a feature added.
How can I get the cat|ID of the feature just created?